# how to see if datetime is between start and end time of different dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following two dataframes in pandas

```
   df   
   code    start_time          end_time             start    end     flag
   0      2018-08-01 06:30:00  2018-08-01 06:40:00  123      145     0
   1      2018-08-01 06:40:00  2018-08-01 06:50:00  145      150     0
   2      2018-08-01 07:10:00  2018-08-01 07:20:00  155      160     1

  df1
  code   occur_time           Ack_time               Alarm
  0      2018-08-01 06:50:00  2018-08-01 08:00:00    437           
  1      2018-08-01 06:40:00  2018-08-01 07:10:00    430          
  2      2018-08-01 07:10:00  2018-08-01 07:20:00    456
```

The condition I want to check is,in `df` dataframe `flag` should be 1 then for that perticular row `start_time` should be between `occur_time` and `Ack_time` and `Alarm` should be `437`

My desired dataframe would be

```
  df   
  code    start_time          end_time             start  end   flag  manual
  0      2018-08-01 06:30:00  2018-08-01 06:40:00  123    145   0     1
  1      2018-08-01 06:40:00  2018-08-01 06:50:00  145    150   0     0 
  2      2018-08-01 07:10:00  2018-08-01 07:20:00  155    160   1     0
```

Comment: Can't you just concatenate both dataframes for this check? By the way, it's really unclear how to contruct the manual column of your output dataframe and it is also unclear what should happen to the output if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.loc[:, 'manual'] = (df1.occur_time.between(df.start_time, df.end_time) \
                       & (df1.Alarm == 437) \
                       & df.flag).apply(int)
```

EDIT: Added checking the flag also.

Comment: Can we also check if the `df['flag'] == 1` in above code?

Comment: Sure, check out my edit. Btw, if "flag" values are always either 0 or 1, there's no need to check for == 1, as 1 behaves as a boolean as is.

Comment: What if my no of rows in two dataframes are different?Will it still work?

Comment: Its showing error as `can compare only identical labeled series`

Comment: It won't work for different number of rows, they need to aligned.

Do you have an index that should be consistent for both dataframes? Then you can "sync" their indices by using `df.reindex(<some_index>)`